# Machine Learning alternative for hashing

Tags: machine-learning, anomaly-detection, outlier, markov-process

Is there a Machine Learning technique that can used to detect the slightest change in data? I know this can be done using a hash but I was just wondering if there is any machine learning technique out there that can do this as well or close to it.

Comment: Before answering, just to get one thing straight:

"that can be used to detect the slightest change in data?" - you want to detect similar data, right?

Comment: @AntonioJurić not really similar data. Just to detect changes in data. Kind of like an anomaly detection. A change in data (addition or subtraction) results in an alarm of some sort.

Comment: But if you just want to detect the slightest change in the data (and not to detect similar data) - then machine learning really seems like overkill since there are other methods which do exactly that. Like the one you mention: hashing, ...

Comment: @AntonioJurić I know, it was just a shower thought. I was wondering how that could be implemented. But yeah, machine learning would not be efficient.